# WSO2 APIM 3.0.0 REFUSED TO START AFTER EDITING master-datasources.xml file

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I installed wso2am-3.0.0 as a service on linux machine and i changed the default database to mysql by editing the master-datasources.xml file. However, when i start the service by running **sudo service wso2am-3.0.0 start**, I got stucked here as shown below:

```
TID: [2020-02-19 00:16:22,738]  INFO {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Applying Configurations upon new Templates {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser}
TID: [2020-02-19 00:16:22,739]  WARN {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Configurations Changed in :repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser}
TID: [2020-02-19 00:16:22,739]  WARN {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Configurations Changed in :repository/conf/carbon.xml {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser}
TID: [2020-02-19 00:16:22,739]  WARN {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Overriding files in configuration directory /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.0.0 {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser}
```

And nothing else happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From API Manager v3.0.0, we have introduced a new configuration model where now you have a deployment.toml to configure. You don't need to touch any xml config files. deployment.toml can be found in repository/conf location. Although you change the configs in xml files, those will be overridden when server starts up.

Please refer how you can change databases to mysql - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/InstallAndSetup/SettingUpDatabases/ChangingDefaultDatabases/changing-to-mysql/